# Roslaunch blocking message publication

Tags: ros, roslauch, rosrun, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two simple Python nodes, a publisher outputting data at /mypub/data and a subscriber consuming that data.

When I run them using rosrun, everything works perfectly, but when I launch each of them using roslaunch, the subscriber never receives any topics being output by the publisher.

Logging inside the publisher shows messages are being published and `rosmsg list|grep -i mypackage` shows my message type has been generated, but when my publisher is running and publishing, `rostopic echo /mypub/data` shows nothing and appears to hang.

My publisher's launch file is trivial:

```
<launch>
   <node name="mypub" pkg="mypackage" type="mypub_node.py" output="screen">
   </node>
</launch>
```

And the node seems to start up cleanly with the output:

```
started roslaunch server http://localhost:60558/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES
  /
    mypub (mypackage/mypub_node.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[mypub-1]: started with pid [12609]
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.532694] init_node, name[/mypub], pid[12609]
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.535395] binding to 0.0.0.0 0
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.537606] bound to 0.0.0.0 49259
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.540770] ... service URL is rosrpc://localhost:49259
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.542789] [/mypub/get_loggers]: new Service instance
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.554825] ... service URL is rosrpc://localhost:49259
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.556568] [/mypub/set_logger_level]: new Service instance
  self.packet_pub = rospy.Publisher('~data', msgs.Data)
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458106329.639749] ... service URL is rosrpc://localhost:49259
```

If I start it instead with rosrun, like:

```
rosrun mypackage mypub_node.py
```

it again seems to start cleanly, with output:

```
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.209104] init_node, name[/mypub], pid[13349]
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.211273] binding to 0.0.0.0 0
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.212995] bound to 0.0.0.0 37078
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.215700] ... service URL is rosrpc://localhost:37078
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.217320] [/mypub/get_loggers]: new Service instance
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.228779] ... service URL is rosrpc://localhost:37078
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.230445] [/mypub/set_logger_level]: new Service instance
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.320980] ... service URL is rosrpc://localhost:37078
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1458107532.323380] [/mypub/packet_write]: new Service instance
```

and then `rostopic echo /mypub/data` successfully shows the messages.

What's the difference between these two calls? Why is roslaunch preventing messages from being visible outside the node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229189/roslaunch-blocking-message-publication/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-16**:
Do you see your topic with `rostopic list` ? Is your node doing anything other than publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that my node was initializing itself with the name "MyPub", whereas in the launch file I was using "mypub". I didn't realize the XML name overrode the node's internal name or that it was case sensitive. After I made them the same, everything started working.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0